# ES6 Modules - Global Variables

Tags: javascript

I was trying to create a quick pub-sub system based out of localStorage. The process made me realize that my understanding of how ES6 modules work is incomplete.

```
const subscribers = {};
export default {
  subscribe (key, callback) {
    if (!Array.isArray(subscribers[key])) {
      subscribers[key] = [callback];
    } else {
      subscribers[key] = [...subscribers[key], callback];
    }
  },
  publish (key, value) {
    window.localStorage[key] = value;
    subscribers[key].forEach(cb => cb(value));
  }
};
```

I imported this module whenever I wanted to subscribe/publish to a key in localStorage. The problem is that the subscribers object gets reinitialized everytime the module is imported.

Is there a way to do retain the subscribers object without polluting window? I assumed that the import statement will only execute the file once only for the first time it is imported.

Thanks.

Comment: As browsers don't currently support modules, what packaging system are you using?

Comment: Webpack + Babel + ES6 Modules

Comment: Can you show how you're using it? All imports of that should be sharing the same module state (and do, when I test it in babel-node).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Please refer to my answer below, it was a mistake at my end :-)

Comment: Things that turn out to be typos like that are best just deleted. I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is an oversight at my end.

I made a typo when importing this module (capitalization), I specified the wrong filename.

> There is another module with an equal name when case is ignored. This
>   can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with
>   other case-semantic. Rename module if multiple modules are expected or
>   use equal casing if one module is expected.

This caused the module to reinitialize.

Please correct me if I am wrong, but I believe a module will be only executed once for the entire application, when imported for the first time.

Thanks.